# org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: Failed to start service

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

This should be the very common problem that everyone will be facing while deployment. You will be failing if you deploy a web archive `(.war)` under `/` context.

The error in JBoss console will be like this,

> Internal Server Error
>       {
>           "outcome" => "failed",
>           "failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: Failed to start service
>           Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBWEB000250: Child container with name  already exists"}},
>           "rolled-back" => true
>       }

The problem comes because of the following configuration in `standalone.xml`

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix this,

`enable-welcome-root="true"` to be made `"false"`

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```